# TIBCO BW5- Mavenization using maven commands

Tags: maven, maven-2, tibco, tibco-business-works

I am trying to mavenize tibco bw5 existing projects using maven commands based on https://fastconnect.github.io/tibco-factory/bw-maven-plugin/mavenization.html

According to which,

1. I created a folder and then excecuted : "**mvn archetype:generate-DarchetypeGroupId=fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype-client-root-project** " which creates a root folder with a root POM.xml.
2. Then i placed an existing bw5 project folder that contains vcrepo.dat and bw code, in the root folder and tried to mavenize the project :
   **mvn bw:mavenize-bw-projects -DrootProjectArtifactId=rootmavenartifact -DrootProjectGroupId=com.rootmavengroupId -DrootProjectVersion=1.0.0 -DdoIt=true**

which gives me follwing error and mavenisation is not successful

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Root for ClientMavenProj project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ rootProject ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Root for ClientMavenProj project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- bw-maven-plugin:2.4.1:mavenize-bw-projects (default-cli) @ rootProject ---
    [INFO] Scanning recursively 'C:\trialMaven2\rootProject' with patterns '[**/]'
    [INFO] ---
    [INFO] rootProject
    [INFO]   Location of the BW project    : tibco_practise
    [INFO]   Location of the project (POM) : C:\trialMaven2\rootProject
    [INFO]   The root project is           : com.rootmavengroupId:rootmavenartifact:1.0.0
    [INFO]   The root project location is  :
    [INFO]   Mavenized project will be     : com.rootmavengroupId:rootproject:1.0.0
    [INFO]
    **[WARNING] Mavenization failed : No common path element found for 'C:\trialMaven2\rootProject\C:\trialMaven2\rootProject' and ''**
    [INFO]
    [INFO] 1 project was found.
    **[INFO] 1 project failed the mavenization.
    [INFO] 0 project was successfully mavenized.**
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 5.286 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-13T21:51:41+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 18M/269M
    [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note:Attaching root pom for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<relativePath>` tag for the parent path

```
<parent>
    <groupId>fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco</groupId>
    <artifactId>fc-tibco-factory</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <relativePath>PARENT_RELATIVE_PATH</relativePath>
</parent>
```